# need some resource on database learning

Tags: database, resources

I am becoming confused while learning database programming (SQL/MySQL etc). Sometime I can not install software like the video tutorial. Sometime I can not run command properly.

Can anyone suggest me some beginner friendly free resource to learn database? (from your experience)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a SQL Tutorial by freeCodeCamp which is available on YouTube [SQL Tutorial - Full course for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXV3zeQKqGY)